# How to capture unoccupied enemy-controlled territories?

Tags: axis-and-allies

How do I capture them? (besides tanks blitzing). That would not work if im trying to capture an island. Just move in with a bunch of infantry and claim it for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture an unoccupied enemy terrority either by blitzing through it (as you mentioned in the question) or by moving a land unit into the territory.  It is treated as a combat move and is essentially as if you are fighting a battle against zero defenders (which you automatically win)

Answer (score 2):

On an island, there wouldn't be an opportunity for a tank blitz (unless it started from a land zone two zones away).

But tanks or infantry can assault an island (or any coastal region) from a transport, possibly with air or battleship support. If they "outlast" the enemy defenders, the survivors can move ashore and occupy the island.

Tanks or infantry attacking an unoccupied island have "outlasted" the enemy defenders, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, for islands:

Move a transport into an adjacent (emptied) sea tile; unload 1 to 2 infantry or 1 tank onto the island.